# Python Neo4j using string variables in Cypher statements

Tags: python, string, variables, neo4j, statements

I am obviously misunderstanding something  about the format of the session.run method in the python Neo4j module.

This works:

```
session.run("statement1"
            "statement2"
             "statement3"
             "statement4", variable list)
```

But now I need to modify the strings externally to the method:
eg I would like to do

```
s1 = "statement1"
s2 = "statement2"
session.run(s1
            s2
            "statement3"
            "statement4", variable list)
```

So that I can modify the statement in ways that cannot be handled by the .run method - eg modifying labels on the fly.

But I get a syntax error

I don't understand why this does not work. What am I doing wrong? How can I introduce variables such as label names into a run command like that?

Thanks

---

Actual code is this:

```
    s1 = "MERGE (a:Animal:Female {tag: {tag}})"
    session.run(s1
             " MERGE (d:Animal:Female {tag: {dam}})"
            "MERGE (s:Animal:Male {tag: {sire}})"
            "MERGE (d)-[:DamTo{dob:{dob}}]->(a)"
            "MERGE (s)-[:SireTo{dob:{dob}}]->(a)" , tag = tag, dob = dob, dam = dam, sire = sire )
```

Error message:

```
" MERGE (d:Animal:Female {tag: {dam}})"
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I get a not very helpful:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Added details of code and error message to original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated. However, a string variable does not support automatic concatenation.

Try changing this:

```
         s1
         " MERGE (d:Animal:Female {tag: {dam}})"
```

to this:

```
         s1 +
         " MERGE (d:Animal:Female {tag: {dam}})"
```

The other automatic concatenations should still work.

Comment: Thanks. It is as simple as that!

I had not realized that Python was doing a concatenation in that statement; I had imagined that **.run** was doing something clever with those separate strings. I had tried presenting all the statements as a single string, that did not work because I had tried to separate them with commas or semi-colons.